# Why Java provides garbage collection?

Tags: java

I understand that memory deallocation is necessary in any language. But java provides it and frees programmers from worries of memory de-allocation.

Now, what I have gathered is, only benefit of java providing garbage collection mechanism is that, overhead of programmers is reduced. But JVM's overhead is increased.

My doubt is this the only benefit of java garbage collection or I am missing some other point?

Comment: GC is not necessary in any language. In fact, there's lot of languages without it, namely C.

Comment: you understand that gc would be "necessary in any language", but "only benefit of java providing garbage collection mechanism is that, overhead of programmers is reduced"? aren't you contradicting yourself?

Comment: @el.pescado it's in `C` too, it's called `free`. Only programmers do it 'manually'

Comment: I meant to say, memory deallocation is necessary in any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On paper, your assertion that programmer-overhead is reduced is 'correct', but I think you underestimate the amount of effort that good memory management takes in 'manual' collection languages like C, etc. Not just the amount of discipline needed to ensure all malloc'd memory is freed, but the hours spent debugging memory leaks, etc. when things go wrong.

A real-life analogy is good.....

How about if we all had to displose of our own waste (sewage, garbage, etc.). Sure, we can do it, but isn't it nice to have people come to our house to pick it up, recycle it properly, etc.

Comment: Having debugged classloader leaks and similar quite a lot, I must say having GC doesn't mean one is free from debugging memory leaks.

Comment: True, been there, but, the threshold at which people encounter memory issues with Java is far higher than languages like C

Comment: +1 for real-life analogy :). So, I am not missing anything. Its just to make our life easy.

Comment: +1 and more productive writing code rather than cleaning up garbage.

Answer (score 1):

> - First, it can make you more productive. When programming in non-garbage-collected languages you can spend many late hours (or days or weeks) chasing down an elusive memory problem. When programming in Java you can use that time more advantageously by getting ahead of schedule or simply going home to have a life.
> - A second advantage of garbage collection is that it helps ensure program integrity. Garbage collection is an important part of Java's security strategy. Java programmers are unable to accidentally (or purposely) crash the Java virtual machine by incorrectly freeing memory.
>
> A potential disadvantage of a garbage-collected heap is that it adds an overhead that can affect program performance. The Java virtual machine has to keep track of which objects are being referenced by the executing program, and finalize and free unreferenced objects on the fly. This activity will likely require more CPU time than would have been required if the program explicitly freed unnecessary memory. In addition, programmers in a garbage-collected environment have less control over the scheduling of CPU time devoted to freeing objects that are no longer needed.

[source.](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/gcP.html)